# How to click into row of datagirid in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a web page and a gird on it.

I want to click on a cell of my grid in Selenium IDE.

but this code doesn't work.

```
    selenium.click("//tr[@id='row8']/td[2]");
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>

    <td>id=cellid </td>

    <td></td>
</tr>
```

in the target locator field give either  id ,name,css or xpath

Comment: I have a table in which I have used datagrid &dataColumn.    <td>
<v:datagrid  id="instalments_grid"  selectable="true">
 <v:dataColumn alignment="right"
    id="unitOfMeasure"
     toolTipText="Click to sort"
       text="${messages.countunit}"
       width="70"
      value="#{row.quantity.unit.description}"
    cellToolTipText="#{row.quantity.unit.description} ">
</v:datagrid>

</td>               and datacolumn data in the database shows,,,I  want to use the Selenium IDE that click on row 8 of this data ,but this code doesn't work.